# How to get results of AWS Glue Job when executing via API?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-glue

I executed an AWS Glue Job via API Gateway to start the job run. The job run is successful. But the result of the Script (print of a result) has not gotten through the execution. Only job run ID comes as the response. Is there any way to get the result of the job through an API?

Answer (score 1):

For glue anything you print or log goes into cloud watch
You have an option of adding a handler in your logger that writes to a stream and push that stream to a file in s3. Or better yet, create a StringIO object , store your result to it and then send that to s3

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable suggestion! I am planning to write the result to an S3 bucket and invoke a lambda to retrieve the file content via API Gateway. In by Lambda function, I have to hardcode values in the python script itself. Is there any way to make it more dynamic?

Comment: Pass the data through the event object in your lambda when you call it via the api